# Passing a condition into a function parameter

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something like this:

```
public bool IsBetween(Condition c)
{
    if(c) return true;
    else return false;
}

public static int main()
{
    // Returns true if 1 < x < 10
    bool b1 = IsBetween(x => x > 1 && x < 10);

    // Returns true if 100 < x < 1000
    bool b2 = IsBetween(x => x > 100 && x < 1000); 
}
```

But the question is how do I declare such a function, and how do I pass the variable that I want to compare `x` into this function?

Comment: where does `x` get supplied?

Comment: i really don't see any advantage in this over using a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to the correct notation.  Any of the following delegate types can work, but predicate is the one that closely matches your meaning:

```
using Condition = Predicate<int>;
// using Condition = Converter<int, bool>
// using Condition = Func<int, bool>

public bool IsBetween(Condition c)
{
```

You need to supply the actual value of `x` when you call it:

```
    if (c(42)) return true;
    else return false;
```

But this `if (test) return true; else return false;` is an anti-pattern, just

```
    return c(42);
```

is better.

```
}
```

Finally, you already have the correct lambda notation for defining the condition

```
public static int main()
{
    // Returns true if 1 < x < 10
    bool b1 = IsBetween(x => x > 1 && x < 10);

    // Returns true if 100 < x < 1000
    bool b2 = IsBetween(x => x > 100 && x < 1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the type of `x` to be `T`, use [`Predicate<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Predicate<int> betweenOneAndTen = x => x > 1 && x < 10;
Predicate<int> betweenHundredAndThousand = x => x > 100 && x < 1000;

var rnd = new Random(123);
for (int i = 0 ; i != 100 ; i++) {
    int n = rnd.Next(1500);
    bool a = betweenOneAndTen(n);
    bool b = betweenHundredAndThousand(n);
    Console.WriteLine("N={0} 1 < {0} < 10 is {1}, 100 < {0} < 1000 is {2}", n, a, b);
}
```